# Assigning items to groups with features

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations, z3, z3py

I have a problem where I am to assign variables to sets. Each set has a limit of variables that can be assigned to it and each variable can be assigned to some subset of the total sets.

Example:

- `a` can be in sets `A` or `B`
- `b` can be in sets `B`
- `c` can be in sets `A` or `B`
- `d` can be in sets `A`

Thus, we can have `A: a, d; B: b, c` or `A: c, d; B: a,b` (order of variables within set does not matter).

I am currently doing the following using z3 (written using solve here, can also be represented using Solver). By the below code, if `a_in_A = True` then the variable `a` is in set `A`.

```
solve(If(a_in_B, 1, 0) + If(b_in_B, 1, 0) + If(c_in_B, 1, 0) <= 2,
      If(a_in_A, 1, 0) + If(c_in_A, 1, 0) + If(d_in_A, 1, 0) <= 2, 
      If(a_in_A, 1, 0) + If(a_in_B, 1, 0) == 1, 
      If(b_in_B, 1, 0) == 1, 
      If(c_in_A, 1, 0) + If(c_in_B, 1, 0) == 1, 
      If(d_in_A, 1, 0) == 1)
```

I can weight the variables within the set, such as below. In this case, we would be left with only `A: a, d; B: b, c` as a solution, although this can be expanded.

```
solve(If(a_in_B, 4, 0) + If(b_in_B, 3, 0) + If(c_in_B, 3, 0) <= 6,
      If(a_in_A, 4, 0) + If(c_in_A, 3, 0) + If(d_in_A, 3, 0) <= 7, 
      If(a_in_A, 4, 0) + If(a_in_B, 4, 0) == 4, 
      If(b_in_B, 3, 0) == 3, 
      If(c_in_A, 3, 0) + If(c_in_B, 3, 0) == 3, 
      If(d_in_A, 3, 0) == 3)
```

However, I would also like to input in other features like `c` must come in a set after `a`. Thus, we would be reduced to only the solution of `A: a, d; B: b, c`. How would I add these requirements to the z3 solver expression (or another way altogether)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any programming task, there could be many ways to solve this problem. I think the following would be the most idiomatic way of doing so in z3py. Note the use of the internal `Set` type, which is modeled internally by arrays. I'm choosing integers as the elements of the sets, though you can make this an enumerated type (or some other base type) if you like:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

a, b, c, d = Ints('a b c d')
allElems = [a, b, c, d]
s.add(Distinct(allElems))

# We have 2 sets
A, B = Consts ('A B', SetSort(IntSort()))
allSets = [A, B]

# Generic requirement: Every element belongs to some set:
for e in allElems:
    belongs = False;
    for x in allSets:
        belongs = Or(belongs, IsMember(e, x))
    s.add(belongs)

# Capacity requirements
sizeA, sizeB = Ints('sizeA sizeB')
s.add(SetHasSize(A, sizeA))
s.add(SetHasSize(B, sizeB))
s.add(sizeA <= 2)
s.add(sizeB <= 2)

# Problem specific requirements:
s.add(Or(IsMember(a, A), IsMember(a, B)))
s.add(IsMember(b, B))
s.add(Or(IsMember(c, A), IsMember(c, B)))
s.add(IsMember(d, A))

# c must be in a set that's after a's set
s.add(Implies(IsMember(a, A), IsMember(c, B)))
s.add(Not(IsMember(a, B))) # otherwise there wouldn't be a place to put c!

r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print("Solver said: " + r)
```

Note how the cardinality/capacity requirements are stated using `sizeA`, `sizeB` variables. You can generalize and write your helper functions to automate most of this stuff.

Your original problem definition was rather ambiguous, but I hope the above gives you an idea on how to proceed. In particular, we can easily express the requirement that `c` belongs to a set "after" `a` since we have only two sets around:

```
s.add(Implies(IsMember(a, A), IsMember(c, B)))
s.add(Not(IsMember(a, B))) # otherwise there wouldn't be a place to put c!
```

but if you have more than two sets you might want to write a helper function that walks over the sets (much like I did in the "Generic requirement" part) to automate this as well. (Essentially, you'd say if `A` is in a specific set, then `c` is in one of the "later" sets. When you come to the last set, you'd need to say `a` is not in it, as otherwise there would be no place to put `c` in.)

When I run the above program, it prints:

```
[A = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 1, k!0 == 4)),
 b = 5,
 a = 1,
 d = 4,
 sizeB = 2,
 c = 3,
 sizeA = 2,
 B = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 3, k!0 == 5)),
 Ext = [else -> 5]]
```

This can be a bit hard to read, but you'll get used to it in no time! Important parts are:

```
a = 1
b = 5
c = 3
d = 4
```

Above should be self-explanatory. Since we wanted to represent elements with integers, z3 picked these ones. (Note we said `Distinct` to make sure they weren't the same.) You can use an enum-sort here if you want.

The next part is the representation of the sets `A` and `B`:

```
A = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 1, k!0 == 4)),
B = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 3, k!0 == 5)),
```

What this is saying is that `A` contains the elements `1` and `4` (i.e., `a` and `d`), while `B` contains the elements `3` and `5` (i.e., `b` and `c`). You can mostly ignore the `Lambda` part and the funny looking `k!0` symbol, and read it as follows: Any value that is either `1` `OR` `4` belongs to `A`. And similarly for `B`.

The `sizeA` and `sizeB` variables should be self-explanatory.

You can ignore the `Ext` value. It's used for internal purposes by z3.

Hope this shows you how you can structure even more complex constraints in a declarative way using built-in support for `Set`s.

Comment: Ah this is very helpful! One part I'm confused about is how would I make the `Problem specific requirements` and `c must be in a set that's after a's set` extend to many sets and many requirements. I know you touched upon the latter in your answer, but I can't seem to figure it out. With the former, how would I format the multiple "or" statements (in a loop fashion) such that each variable is able to cover many sets (I presume "or" can only have 2 items in it)?

Comment: `Or` can take a list argument. I suggest you give it a try, and ask a specific separate question on stack-overflow if you get stuck, showing the code you tried. Also, accepting answers tell other people the problem is addressed. (See the "checkmark" next to the answer.)

Comment: I was having some trouble expanding the code you showed. I made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642575) as you suggested. I was hoping you could take a look as you answered this question so have the background.