# Outputting z3 model output in a readable format

Tags: python, output, z3, z3py

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606938/) question about assigning variables to a set but am struggling to understand how I would output the `s.model()` results in a readable format.

While I may be able to interpret the following

```
[A = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 1, k!0 == 4)),
 b = 5,
 a = 1,
 d = 4,
 sizeB = 2,
 c = 3,
 sizeA = 2,
 B = Lambda(k!0, Or(k!0 == 3, k!0 == 5)),
 Ext = [else -> 5]]
```

It would be unreasonable for users to interpret that. I would like to get the output in a format that is easy to read/work with (ex. `{A: [a, d], B: [b, c]}`). How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.. You can extract the model in a programmatic way and display it in any way you like. For the program you mentioned, simply add the following at the end, after the `r = s.check()` line:

```py
if r != sat:
    print("Solver said: %s" % r)
else:
    m = s.model()
    print("A = %s" % [e for e in allElems if m.evaluate(m[A][e])])
    print("B = %s" % [e for e in allElems if m.evaluate(m[B][e])])
```

With this addition, when I run that program, it prints:

```
A = [a, d]
B = [b, c]
```

which is, I believe, what you're looking for.

Obviously, you can extract these values, manipulate them, even assert new constraints based on the model you found, and query for more. The API is quite flexible, and if you want to program further with it I recommend giving a read through https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm