# z3 - unexpected output/not sure what output means

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63603982) and got a [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63606938). However, I had to extend this answer to work with a large set of data (code below). However, in doing so, I get an output that I do not understand.

Sometimes, I get a `unsat` and other times I get a `sat` for `s.check()`; sometimes the `s.check()` and `s.model()` take very long to run and other times, seconds. However, what I do not understand is when I get output like this:

```
[else ->
 Or(Var(0) == 7,
    Var(0) == 13,
    Var(0) == 43,
    Var(0) == 20,
    Var(0) == 26,
    Var(0) == 16,
    Var(0) == 45,
    Var(0) == 21,
    Var(0) == 36,
    Var(0) == 5,
    Var(0) == 6,
    Var(0) == 35,
    Var(0) == 50,
    Var(0) == 28,
    Var(0) == 10,
    Var(0) == 27,
    Var(0) == 34,
    Var(0) == 14,
    Var(0) == 51,
    Var(0) == 48,
    Var(0) == 47,
    Var(0) == 19)]
[else ->
 Or(Var(0) == 22, Var(0) == 15, Var(0) == 8, Var(0) == 24)]
[else ->
 Or(Var(0) == 44, Var(0) == 17, Var(0) == 46, Var(0) == 11)]
[else ->
 Or(Var(0) == 49,
    Var(0) == 42,
    Var(0) == 9,
    Var(0) == 31,
    Var(0) == 12,
    Var(0) == 18,
    Var(0) == 23,
    Var(0) == 34)]
```

I'm not sure what the `else -> ...` means and the balance of variables in each set is off (not to mention there is no variable `44`). I would appreciate any help. The full code is below.

```
in_var_list = []
in_var_list.append(("var 1", 4, [3]))
in_var_list.append(("var 2", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 3", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 4", 4, [4, 5, 6], ["var 3"]))
in_var_list.append(("var 6", 4, [4, 5, 6], ["var 3"]))
in_var_list.append(("var 7", 3, [4, 5, 6], ["var 4"]))
in_var_list.append(("var 8", 3, [3, 4]))
in_var_list.append(("var 9", 3, [5]))
in_var_list.append(("var 10", 3, [6], ["var 9"]))
in_var_list.append(("var 11", 3, [3, 5]))
in_var_list.append(("var 12", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 13", 3, [4]))
in_var_list.append(("var 14", 3, [3]))
in_var_list.append(("var 15", 3, [5]))
in_var_list.append(("var 16", 3, [5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 17", 4, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 18", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 19", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]))
in_var_list.append(("var 20", 3, [4, 5, 6], ["var 2"]))
in_var_list.append(("var 21", 3, [5, 6], ["var 2", "var 1"]))
        #variable name, variable size, possible sets, prerequisites

in_set_list = [(3, 18), (4, 18), (5, 18), (6, 18)]
            #set name, max set size

from z3 import *

s = Solver()

allElems = {vari[0]: Int(vari[0]) for vari in in_var_list}
s.add(Distinct(list(allElems.values())))

#Python 3.6 - dictionaries are ordered
#split into sets
allSets = {c_set[0]: Const(str(c_set[0]), SetSort(IntSort())) for c_set in in_set_list}

#Generic requirement: Every element belongs to some set:
for e in allElems.values():
    belongs = False;
    for x in allSets.values():
        belongs = Or(belongs, IsMember(e, x))
    s.add(belongs)

#capacity requirements
for c_set in in_set_list:
  c_set_size = Int(c_set[1])
  s.add(SetHasSize(allSets[c_set[0]], c_set_size))
  s.add(c_set_size <= c_set[1])

#vari set requirements
for vari in in_var_list:
  set_mem_list = []
  for c_set in vari[2]:
    set_mem_list.append(IsMember(allElems[vari[0]], allSets[c_set]))
  s.add(Or(set_mem_list))

#pre-set requirements
vari_dict = {vari[0]: vari for vari in in_var_list}
for vari in in_var_list:
  try: #may not include preset
    for prereq in in_var_list[3]:
      for i, c_set in enumerate(in_set_list):
        if c_set[0] in vari_dict[prereq][2]:
          imps = []
          for subc_set in in_set_list[i+1:]:
            imps.append(IsMember(allElems[vari[0]], allSets[subc_set]))
          s.add(Implies(IsMember(allElems[prereq], allSets[c_set[0]], Or(imps))))
          s.add(Not(IsMember(allElems[prereq], allSets[in_set_list[-1]])))
  except:
    pass

r = s.check()
print(r)
if r == sat:
  modout = s.model()
else:
  raise ValueError('unsat - too many constraints, cannot fit all variables as given')

vari_out = {modout[allElems[vari]]: vari for vari in allElems}
print(vari_out)

set_out = dict()
for s in allSets:
  set_out[s] = modout[allSets[s]].as_list()

rets = dict()
for s in allSets:
  rets[s] = []
  for c in (set_out)[s][0].children():
    try:
      rets[s].append(vari_out[c.children()[1]])
    except:
      pass
print(rets)

"""# print results"""

from pprint import pprint
pprint(rets)
```

Comment: Stack-overflow works the best if you can post a minimum-reproducible example. See here for guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Try to reduce your program to a minimum that exhibits the problem, and you'll get better guidance as to how to proceed. And in all likelihood, you'll solve the issue you're facing in the process and it'll be quite educational. Best of luck!

Comment: @alias I'm having trouble minimizing the code as the same code is giving me different results if run multiple times. I just tried rerunning it and got 4 "else" clauses instead of 2 "else" and 2 "lambda" clauses. Is this expected and how would I overcome this?

Comment: z3 internally uses random numbers; so if there are multiple models available, it is possible that you'll get a different one each time you run your program. (Though a `sat` problem should *not* become `unsat` and vice-versa. That'd be a bug.) I'd start by reducing the number of variables: Instead of the 21 you have, start with just a few, and make sure you've a solid program that works as expected before continuing.

Comment: Note that `for c_set in in_set_list:   c_set_size = Int(c_set[1])` creates `Int`s with the numbers 18,18,18 and 8 as name. That looks a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints are clearly unsatisfiable, as the sum of all variable weights is higher than the sum of all maximum set weights. Unfortunately, in general there is no easy way to obtain an explanation from Z3 for why constraints are unsatisfiable.

Compared to the examples in this [tutorial](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm) and [this book](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf), the current example seems rather simple, and it should run quite quickly, even for many more similar constraints. I didn't check the details of your implementation, but maybe something allows the variables to get very high (instead of being constraint to the 4 given sets). In that case Z3 would generate many possibilities that are rejected in a later stage.

To get a more consistent behavior, it could help to restart Python for every run. (I am testing in the console of PyCharm, and restart the console each time).

Following the examples at the tutorial, I would tackle the constraints as follows. To obtain a satisfiable example, 4 is added to each of the desired set sizes.

```py
in_var_list = [("var 1", 4, [3]), ("var 2", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 3", 3, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 4", 4, [4, 5, 6], ["var 3"]), ("var 6", 4, [4, 5, 6], ["var 3"]), ("var 7", 3, [4, 5, 6], ["var 4"]), ("var 8", 3, [3, 4]), ("var 9", 3, [5]), ("var 10", 3, [6], ["var 9"]), ("var 11", 4, [3, 5]), ("var 12", 4, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 13", 4, [4]), ("var 14", 4, [3]), ("var 15", 4, [5]), ("var 16", 4, [5, 6]), ("var 17", 4, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 18", 4, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 19", 4, [3, 4, 5, 6]), ("var 20", 4, [4, 5, 6], ["var 2"]), ("var 21", 4, [5, 6], ["var 2", "var 1"])]  # variable name, variable size, possible sets, prerequisites
in_set_list = [(3, 18), (4, 18), (5, 18), (6, 8)]  # set name, max set size


from z3 import Int, Solver, Or, And, Sum, If, sat

# add empty list to tupples of length 3
in_var_list = [tup if len(tup) == 4 else (*tup, []) for tup in in_var_list]

print("sum of all weights:", sum([weight for _, weight, _, _ in in_var_list]))
print("sum of max weights:", sum([max_ssize for _, max_ssize in in_set_list]))


s = Solver()
v = {varname: Int(varname) for varname, *_ in in_var_list}

for name, weight, pos_sets, prereq in in_var_list:
    s.add(Or([v[name] == p for p in pos_sets])) # each var should be in one of its possible sets
    s.add(And([v[r] < v[name] for r in prereq])) # each prerequisit should be in an earlier set
print("*** Test: adding 4 to the maximum sizes ***")
for snum, max_ssize in in_set_list:
    s.add(Sum([If(v[name] == snum, weight, 0) for name, weight, _, _ in in_var_list]) <= max_ssize + 4)
    # the sum of all the weights in a set should be less than or equal to the desired size


res = s.check()
print("result:", res)
if res == sat:
    m = s.model()

    set_assignments = {name: m.evaluate(v[name]).as_long() for name, *_ in in_var_list}
    print("assignments:", set_assignments)
    for snum, desired_ssize in in_set_list:
        ssize = sum([weight for name, weight, _, _ in in_var_list if set_assignments[name] == snum])
        print(f"set {snum}:", [name for name, *_ in in_var_list if set_assignments[name] == snum],
              f"desired size: {desired_ssize}, effective size: {ssize}")
```

Output:

```
sum of all weights: 74
sum of max weights: 62

assignments: {'var 1': 3, 'var 2': 4, 'var 3': 3, 'var 4': 4, 'var 6': 5, 'var 7': 5, 'var 8': 3, 'var 9': 5, 'var 10': 6, 'var 11': 3, 'var 12': 4, 'var 13': 4, 'var 14': 3, 'var 15': 5, 'var 16': 5, 'var 17': 5, 'var 18': 4, 'var 19': 3, 'var 20': 6, 'var 21': 6}
set 3: ['var 1', 'var 3', 'var 8', 'var 11', 'var 14', 'var 19'] desired size: 18, effective size: 22
set 4: ['var 2', 'var 4', 'var 12', 'var 13', 'var 18'] desired size: 18, effective size: 19
set 5: ['var 6', 'var 7', 'var 9', 'var 15', 'var 16', 'var 17'] desired size: 18, effective size: 22
set 6: ['var 10', 'var 20', 'var 21'] desired size: 8, effective size: 11
```

Comment: I actually mistyped the variables back into the question - it should now be satisfiable as I did get results out as shown in the question. I'm using a Colab session so I guess I'm not restarting the console. Would it still be a problem as the variables persist unless I rerun? How long is "quite quickly"? Upon reading the source code, I understand the variance in calculation time, but I'm not sure how a 10-20 min calculation time stands (given a 1core hyperthreaded Xeon 2.3Ghz processor)

Comment: Why does `v[r] < v[name]` work even without the variables being in ordinal form (ie. I can list `set 3` before `set 1` and it will still show up as such in the final model)? Also, this seems to be *significantly* faster than the code in the question (always within a couple seconds, whereas the code in the question averaged long enough that I usually terminated it and reran in hopes of a quick `sat`). Would you know why? It seems to be identical in what it adds to the model. Related - would you know why the output is so different given seemingly identical `s`?

Comment: For some strange reason your original solution tries out large values for the variables. Values such as 43 don't make sense in this context. This is what makes it slow. Your question about using text instead of numbers for the sets, I never tried out such thing. Maybe this works on some internal numbering that Z3 creates when adding the variable?

Comment: About the internals of Z3 and Z3py I know very little, just that it is an impressive machinery. Developers are working constantly in improving both the engine and the representations.